# Filter with date() on $sql query

Tags: php, sql, date

I'm having problems understanding where to place the conversion to take the unixtime and convert it to the specific month and year.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM logs WHERE clientid = '5604' AND timestamp = 'Jan 13' ";
```

Where would I need to place the `date()` function to filter the timestamp to month and year specified?

Comment: What is the type of `timestamp` field and what is example value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two variables.  Make 1 equal to the 1st day of the year month you want and the 2nd equal to the 1st day of the following year month.  Then it's simply this:

```
where timestamp >= your first variable
and timestamp < your second variable
```

This approach will handle the time component of your timestamp field and will perform faster than if you try to use functions.

Comment: +1 - This performs faster because there is no need to do any processing on the value in the table.  Then, if there is an index on that field, all the SQL Engine needs to do is a range seek on that index, as opposed to a full scan.  ***(Please could the down-voter explain, this is actually an extremely effective answer.)***

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [date litterals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-literals.html) in MySQL must follow one of the below formats:

- YY*MM*DD
- YYYY*MM*DD

`*` means "any <strike>non-digit</strike> non-alphanumeric character or no character at all".

`YY` or `YYYY` is the year with two or four digits.

`MM` and `DD` are the month and day numbers.

Then, if you want to get results for a specific date, you can do something like this:

```
... WHERE DATE(timestamp_field) = '2013-01-13';
```

But actually this query wouldn't be able to use an index on `timestamp_field`. This approach is better because and index on `timestamp_field` could be used:

```
... WHERE timestamp_field >= '2013-01-13' AND timestamp_field < '2013-01-14';
```

Comment: Dan's answer was first, so I already voted there, but this explains in more detail as to why that answer is the way to go.

Comment: there's a 14th or 13th month in the year? Which calendar are you using? ;)

Comment: @chrislondon LOL yeah, I live in a very strange place ;)